# What is meant by memory-mapped video?

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, cpu, cpu-registers

What does memory-mapped video means? For example, on a x8086 Intel CPU, it has a 20 bit address line. Does this memory-mapped means some of the x8086 address lines are hardwired to the video adapter card?

Comment: In a simple implementation, yes. Some number of high-order bits would be used to decode a chip select signal to detect when the video card is accessed, and low order bits would address inside the memory. See also [ISA bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_Standard_Architecture).

Comment: with respect to the x86, memory mapped means not I/O mapped.  The memory/I/O pin is set for memory.   video is/was both I/O and memory mapped, the registers I/O and the video memory, memory mapped.  What is the context there are perhaps other sources of that term.  Please add more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, on a x8086 Intel CPU, it has a 20 bit address line.

**Some background first**

(Unlike most other CPUs) x86 CPUs have two address ranges:

- The actual memory address range (which is accessed by "`mov al, [ds:di]`" for example)

  This memory range is intended for memory.
- The I/O address range which is accessed using the `in` and `out` instructions

  This "memory" range is intended for I/O.

The 8086 actually has 21 address lines: A19-A0 and "M/nIO". The A19-A0 lines contain the actual address and the "M/nIO" line contains the information if the "regular" memory or the I/O range is accessed.

In an x86 PC (*) address 0x00021 in the memory area (M/nIO = 1) is RAM while address 0x0021 in the I/O range (M/nIO = 0) is the interrupt controller.

> What does memory-mapped video means?

"Memory-mapped I/O" means that some device is addressed using the "memory" address space and not using the "I/O" address space:

The video adapter is addressed by reading and writing to the memory addresses 0xA0000-0xBFFFF (depending on the video mode), not by using `in` and `out` instructions.

(For CPUs not having the concept of two address ranges at all - like ARM - it is sometimes also said that the CPU uses memory-mapped I/O. This means that all I/O devices are addressed like memory and there are no special instructions for I/O addressing.)

In the case of video the word might have a more special meaning:

There are systems where you have to access the video memory using multiple I/O accesses:

If you wanted to write data to the video memory using the TMS9918 video chip (which was popular in the 1980s) you first had to write a value specifying the address in the video RAM and then you had to write the actual data. The CPU always had to write both values (video RAM address and data) to the same addresses - independent of the address in video RAM which should be written.

If someone says that the video is **not** memory-mapped I would understand that the system has this behavior.

On x86 PCs (*) this is not the case: A certain address in the video RAM corresponds to a certain CPU address. So if you want to write to 10 different addresses in video RAM the CPU simply has to write data to 10 different addresses.

(*) I don't write x86 "systems" because x86 CPUs are also used in mobile and embedded devices. In such systems the memory layout (which depends on the circuit *outside* the CPU) may differ.

Comment: Although the video memory is part of the address space, legacy video controllers also had I/O ports for programming. Memory mapped I/O is an example where the port addressing is replaced by having what would would otherwise be I/O ports mapped into a physical or virtual address space. If the memory mapped I/O is not hard coded, then during the boot process, the base addresses for a controller's memory mapped I/O are assigned. I don't recall the details of this boot up process.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly hard-wired from the CPU or motherboard side, but all memory accesses were visible on the expansion bus. Any board claiming ownership of an address range would reply to a read or write request from the processor.

It was not at all uncommon to have dedicated RAM-boards on the expansion bus, as many early motherboards could not hold an entire 640k. So nothing magic with some of the expansion RAM located on a video board.

Also, as the early PCs didn't have dedicated graphics processors on the video board, the main CPU would have to do all the rendering anyway and so would need direct access to the graphics buffer for performance reasons.